# Google Home Fan Speed probleme

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I have the following answer from sync :

When i use the google home mini or simulator and say set the fan to low, I receive that device doesnt support that. Can anybody help me ? Documentation seems the problem

```
{
    id: '123',
    type: 'action.devices.types.FAN',
    traits: [
      'action.devices.traits.FanSpeed',
      'action.devices.traits.OnOff'
    ],
    name: {
      defaultNames: ['Sirius Cybernetics Corporation 33321'],
      name: 'Fan',
      nicknames: ['wall fan']
    },
    willReportState: true,
    attributes: {
      availableFanSpeeds: {
        speeds: [{
          speed_name: 'Low',
          speed_values: [{
            speed_synonym: ['low', 'slow'],
            lang: 'en'
          }, {
            speed_synonym: ['low', 'slow'],
            lang: 'de'
          }]
        }, {
          speed_name: 'High',
          speed_values: [{
            speed_synonym: ['high'],
            lang: 'en'
          }, {
            speed_synonym: ['high'],
            lang: 'de'
          }]
        }],
      },
      reversible: true
    },
    deviceInfo: {
      manufacturer: 'Sirius Cybernetics Corporation',
      model: '492134',
      hwVersion: '3.2',
      swVersion: '11.4'
    },
  }
```

EDIT:
I forgot to say that on off work well..

Comment: Can you try typing in the query successfully? Is it case-sensitive?

Comment: I finally managed to make it working, I dont know what exactly fixed it... but thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the attribute `'ordered'` See below

```
attributes: {
      availableFanSpeeds: {
        speeds: [{
          speed_name: 'Low',
          speed_values: [{
            speed_synonym: ['low', 'slow'],
            lang: 'en'
          }, {
            speed_synonym: ['low', 'slow'],
            lang: 'de'
          }]
        }, {
          speed_name: 'High',
          speed_values: [{
            speed_synonym: ['high'],
            lang: 'en'
          }, {
            speed_synonym: ['high'],
            lang: 'de'
          }]
        }],
        'ordered':true
      },
      reversible: true
    }
```